# closure of { z: |z| is rational}

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces

How to find the closure of 
$\{ z: |z|\in\mathbb Q\}$.
I think it is whole complex plane. I was using using the definition of closure, but getting stuck somewhere.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear downvoters, pls tell me the reason of downvoting.

Comment: I am not the down voter but I can understand the one who down voted your question. More context ought to be give. You ought to reveal more of your thoughts... This is not a homework solving machine. (I am a machine though.)

Comment: Please use [edit] to incorporate your attempt to the question. Please don't use image since it's not searchable. Also, here's [MathJax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help you write the notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints:

Write $A = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. The closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{C}$ consists of all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that there exists a sequence $(z_n)$ in $A$ converging to $z$ (depending on your definition of closure, you might need to justify this to yourself).

You're correct in thinking that the closure is $\mathbb{C}$. So consider any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and write $z = r e^{i\theta}$. If $r$ is rational, you're done, so assume it's not. Now, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so we can find a sequence of rationals converging to $r$. Now what can we say?